# SWI-Prolog - Fail to Assert

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

I define an operator as follows:

```
:- op(500, xfx, =>).
```

When I try something like:

```
assert(a => b).
```

Prolog raises an error that says 'No permission to modify static_procedure (=>)/2'.

Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a security, you have to warn SWI that you are going to modify a predicate at runtime:

```
:- dynamic (=>)/2.
```

put at the top of the file should do it.

Comment: Nit: Above is invalid syntax (try GNU to see this). It should be `(=>)/2`

Comment: @false: oh well, I hadn't any interpreter available to check that. Thanks, I'll edit :)

Comment: It's always like that: a predicate indicator has to have brackets if it has a corresponding operator definition. So it is `(;)/2` and `(',')/2`. The quotes serve only to delimit a token - like `'a b'` they are needed independently of operator declarations.

Comment: @false: Ok! I encountered the notation in doc but didn't know if it was specific to SWI or the norm, thanks for those clarifications :)

Comment: Sooner or later you will need the standard - see [tag:iso-prolog] how to get it cheaply.

Comment: Yup I try to refer to it as soon as I have a doubt or have a choice between standard and non standard stuff. Though sometimes I just miss the fact that I'm using non standard stuff, so your clarifications help a lot in those cases :)

Answer (score 4):

You must have meant another symbol in place of `(=>)/2`. Probably `(->)/2` which is a control construct that cannot be modified.

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 32 bits, Version 6.1.3-116-gf1c7e06)
...
?- asserta((a -> b)).
ERROR: asserta/1: No permission to modify static procedure `(->)/2'
ERROR: Defined at /opt/gupu/pl-devel/lib/swipl-6.1.3/boot/init.pl:194
?- op(500, xfx, =>).
true.

?- asserta(a => b).
true.
```

Comment: Right but I think it works if you are using Prolog interactively only! It does not work if you compile the file!!

Comment: Which Prolog system do you refer to? SWI, YAP, B, GNU are all the same.

Comment: It's in the title (SWI-Prolog)

Comment: But apart from that: It *is* a good idea to use dynamic declarations.